# How to convert a string to another so that specific characters aren't allowed in the output?

Tags: java

I have a constraint: I cannot save some chars (like `&` and `=`) in a some special storage.

The problem is that I have strings (user input) that contain these not allowed special chars, which I'd like to save to that storage .

I'd like to convert such string to another string that wouldn't contain these special characters.

I'd like to still be able to convert back to the original string without creating ambiguity.

Any idea how to implement the de/convert? Thanks.

Comment: Use URL encoding?

Comment: Can you tell us what this special storage is?

Comment: Something propriety that saves maps as strings, hence the `&` and `=`.

Comment: @shmosel, what if the no allowed chars were different from `&` and weren't encoded by the URL encoding standard?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: then you can use **your own encoding scheme**
As the example define in my previous comment.

Comment: @Allan, What if the input string was `AaMmPpEeRrSsAaNnDdd`? wouldn't you get an ambiguity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the user input to Hex and save. And convert the hex value back to string. Use these methods.

```
public static String stringToHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
}

public static String hexToString(String arg) {
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(arg);
    return new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

Usage:

```
String h = stringToHex("Perera & Sons");
System.out.println(h);
System.out.println(hexToString(h));
```

OUTPUT

> 506572657261202620536f6e73
>   Perera & Sons

Answer (score 1):

Already pointed out in the comments but  [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) looks like the way to go.

In Java done simply  URLEncoder and URLDecoder

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("My string &with& illegal = characters ", "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Encoded String:" + encoded);

String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Decoded String:" + decoded);
```

[URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)
[URLDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

Comment: what if the non allowed chars were different from `&` and weren't encoded by the URL encoding standard?

Comment: If that is the case then the HEX-alternative might be a more fitting solution.